# Really + [adjective] vs So + [adjective]

Tags: word-choice

> **Sentence A**: She's really sensitive when it comes to talking about her husband.
>
> **Sentence B**: She's so sensitive when it comes to talking about her husband.

My question is: from these two sentences, which one that is more widely-used especially in native English speaker environment.

Comment: Sorry, but proofreading questions are not on-topic for ELL. If you write what specifically you're having trouble with (rather than just "Please correct these sentences"), then I'll reopen the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think *'so* in **this context** adds some *astonishment* with the fact that she's emotional; whereas *really* simply talks about **the fact** that she's emotional.

This may make it clear:

> Yes, I met her for the first time. She's **really** tall (I had some idea about her height and then it turned out to be real!).
>
> Yes, I met her for the first time. She's **so** tall (that I had to look up to talk to her!). (Here, *so* serves as "[To a very great extent or degree](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/SO)" and suggests that the speaker is actually *astonished* and didn't think that she could be *that tall*).

Comment: But "so [adjective]" and "so [adjective] that [clause]" are arguably a different "so". The second "so" means "[adjective] to the extent that [clause]" and is unemotional, whereas the first one is an emotional intensifier.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your examples are typical usage for American English, and they have essentially the same meaning.

The second one might be slightly more emphatic than the first, if only because if *so* isn't strongly emphasized then the listener might think the sentence is incomplete, because they would be expecting a "so ... that ..." construction.

Comment: If the emphatic "so" is intended, but is not voiced properly (making it sound like the to-the-extent-that "so" which requires a complement), then the speaker is essentially making a grammar error.

Comment: @Kaz, my point is that to avoid that error, you must strongly emphasize "so". Which tends to make the "so" sentence sound more emphatic than the "really" sentence.

Comment: Notice that first para in J.R.'s answer essentially makes the erroneous reading of the "so", probably because print doesn't give the ability to indicate the required emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

Sentence B seems a little incomplete. When someone is "so something," that often precedes further clarification:

> *She is so sensitive when it comes to talking about her husband **that I always avoid the subject***.

On the other hand:

> *She is really sensitive when it comes to talking about her husband **so I always avoid the subject**.*

The *so* in the second sentences is a conjunction meaning *therefore*.

The [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/so) dictionary goes into this nuance of the word *so*:

> **so** (*adv*.) (followed by an adjective or adverb and a correlative clause often introduced by *that*) to such an extent  ⇒ *the river is so dirty that it smells*

When *so* is used to simply mean *very*, that may work better with an exclamation point at the end:

> *She is so sensitive when it comes to talking about her husband!*